# Weight the 'randomness' of the 'pick' routine?

Tags: raku, rakudo

I'm creating an API server in Perl 6, using the Cro framework! The purpose of this API is to serve data about Pokemon, and provide endpoints for generating Pokemon based on input data. One of the factors in generation is `gender`, in my PostgreSQL database each reference Pokemon has a `gender-ratio` column which contains a JSON value looking like this:

```
  "gender-ratio": {
    "default": {
      "Male": 0.25,
      "Female": 0.75
    },
    "alolan": {
      "Male": 0.25,
      "Female": 0.75
    }
  },
```

You'll notice I have two keys there called `default` and `alolan`, this is because Pokemon can have various forms but it's mostly irrelevant to this question - what is relevant are the actual gender ratio values. Here's what my generation method looks like currently:

```
method select-gender($pokemon, $form = 'default') {
    enum GENDER ( <Male Female> );

    return GENDER.pick;
}
```

By default `pick` is random, and in this case 50/50. However I'd like to be able to weight the randomness of each option, based on the results of the ratio returned from the database. One of my ideas was to seed the `GENDER` enum with the results of a database query so it would look more like this for the specific example:

```
enum GENDER ( <Male Female Female Female> );
```

Unless anyone else has any better ideas about dynamically altering the behaviour of `pick` based on the result of my `SELECT` statement?

Comment: I did not know it was allowed to have the same values appear more than once in an enum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [Mix](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Mix) and `roll`:

```
my %gender-ratio =  %(default => {
                             "Male" => 0.25,
                             "Female" => 0.75
                         },
                      alolan => {
                             "Male" => 0.25,
                             "Female" =>  0.75
                         }
                     );

my Mix $default = %gender-ratio<default>.Mix;

for ^10 {
    say $default.roll;
}
```

Comment: Presumably `.pick` doesn't work on a `Mix` because it's not obvious what it should do. I'm curious if the error message -- ".pick is not supported on a Mix" -- could reasonably suggest "maybe you want `.roll`?" Perhaps `Failure`s could profitably support a hint attribute (`.hint`?) for such hints?

Comment: So done with https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/e352962284 .  Well, the simple case, as it is still an untyped Failure.